# Passing parameter from Index to New (Symfony 1.2)

Tags: php, symfony1

I need that when I do click in the link "New" from the list (indexSuccess), the new action (executeNew) can recieve the parameter "'commercer_id=' .$commerce_id". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

apps/frontend/config/routing.yml

```
index:
  url:   /New/:commercer_id
  param: { module: index, action: new }
```

Use bellow function in your anchor src

```
url_for(array(
  'module'   => 'index',
  'action'   => 'new',
  'commercer_id'=>$commercer_id,
))
```

To read more about [routers](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05)

Hope it helps!